# Quarkus Consul Config: how to inject application.yaml file from Consul Agent?

Tags: java, quarkus, consul

I am using Quarkus inside a microservice Java application.
I recently started to migrate from Spring Boot to Quarkus itself.

I am having some trouble while migrating "Spring Cloud Consul" to "Quarkus Consul Config". In order to be more specific, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Key 'my/consul/path/application.yaml' not found in Consul
    at io.quarkus.consul.config.runtime.ConsulConfigSourceProvider$1.accept(ConsulConfigSourceProvider.java:66)
    at io.quarkus.consul.config.runtime.ConsulConfigSourceProvider$1.accept(ConsulConfigSourceProvider.java:56)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume$UniOnItemComsumeProcessor.invokeEventHandler(UniOnItemConsume.java:77)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume$UniOnItemComsumeProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemConsume.java:42)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.AsyncResultUni.lambda$subscribe$1(AsyncResultUni.java:35)
    (...)
```

Inside my Consul instance, the key `my/consul/path/application.yaml` corresponds to an `application.yaml` external file that I would like to import from there during the startup phase.

Below you can find my consul config (`application.yaml`):

```
quarkus:
  application:
    name: myapplication
  consul-config:
    enabled: true
    properties-value-keys: my/consul/path/application.yaml
    agent:
      host-port: http://localhost:9500
    prefix: myappprefix
```

If I try to switch from `properties-value-keys` to `properties-raw-value-keys`, I see that my property is not being injected inside my application context:

```
    @ConfigProperty(name = "consultest")
    String test;
```

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property consultest is required but it could not be found in any config source
```

Below you can find the `application.yaml` content (located on Consul):

```
consultest: testtest
```

The intent, here, is to delegate `application.yaml` properties to Consul, divided by environment (dev, test, prod).
I would like to threat my local `application.yaml` file (located in `src/main/resources`) as a `bootstrap.yaml` file, similarly to Spring Boot approach.

How could this be done with Quarkus? Thank you a lot for your support.

Comment: We don't have support for reading YAML from Consul, only raw keys and properties syntax is supported currently.
However we can certainly add support for it. Mind opening an issue in GitHub please?

Comment: Hi @geoand I expected that. I read source code of Java classes that handle tha configuration processing and I found no .yaml extension support.
In order to be sure, I thought to ask for this on Stack Overflow. I can certainly open an issue in GitHub for this topic, I will link that issue to this post.
Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot

Comment: @geoand that's done. I also added a little idea related to the implementation. You can find more at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19127. Thanks again.